# Reading JDBC request in java

Tags: java

Is it possible to read JDBC request from non database host and process the request to other Host which is actual Database host. This should be similar line like Socket listner

Comment: Did You mean  you have a jdbc client at server a and a database in server b and want to connect from a to b using jdbc without connect to database directly?

Comment: not like that. Suppose i have request from a and database at c. but i want to redirect the request from a to b , and b will redirect to c. B knows where c is present. So basically B will act as proxy.

Comment: or is it possible to listen JDBC request at some port like socket server?